# how to pass a template variable to a template tag in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to pass a template variable specific to how the page renders to a template tag function.  I tried this:

```
{{ lesson.description|program_refs:{{site_name}}|safe }}
```

I get the error:

> program_refs requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (without `{{}}` around variable name):

```
{{ lesson.description|program_refs:site_name|safe }}
```